# ALAssetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum block the program in iOS8

Tags: ios8, alassetslibrary

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSMutableDictionary* meta = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]];
    UIImage* img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
if(self.locationManager.location){
        NSDictionary* locationMeta = [self gpsDictionaryForLocation:self.locationManager.location];
        [meta setObject:locationMeta forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary];
    }

    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:img.CGImage metadata:meta completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetUrl, NSError* error){
        //.......
    }
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This code worked fine in iOS7. After I upgraded my device to iOS8, the program was blocked and imagePickerView didn't dismiss.

Is this a bug in iOS8? Anyone can help me?

Comment: Finally, I put "writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum" in the completion block of picker dismiss and it works!!  But I still cannot figure out the problem.